# Import Facebook SDK in Android Studio 2.0

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I downloaded the Facebook SDK 4.8.2 and want to import in the Android Studio 2.0. I added dependencies `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'` and `compile 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+'` on `build.gradle`.
When I try to import the module that is in the Facebook SDK directory, the error as shown below.

[image]

I realized that within the `facebook-android-sdk-4.8.2` directory there are facebook and AudienceNetwork directories. I need to import both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to download the SDK, just add this dependencies in your gradle

```
  compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
```

For 4.8.6 I'm not really sure if it's already in maven central or not but you can try it.